# Magento Product Page Layout

Tags: magento2, xml, product-page

I'm trying to layout my product page. My XML is below. However, They are not showing up in that order. Is there a way to force that?

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/>
<move element="product.price.final" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />
<move element="product.info.simple" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />
<move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />
<move element="product.price.tier" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />
<move element="product.info.sku" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />
<move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />
<move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />
<move element="product.info.addtocart" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />
```

Comment: you should define after attribute to make it work. for example, <move element="product.price.final" destination="product.info.main" after="page.main.title" />. so it shows price after title within "product.info.main"

Comment: Is it correct in leaving before="-" on the first one?

Comment: if it's on proper place then no need to use "move" tag.. Because by default title is the first one to display on that page. everything should be after title

Comment: Im using the move tag to put it into the product.info.main container. Your comment fixed my issue. Will you enter your information as the answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should define after attribute to make it work. for example,

```
<move element="product.price.final" destination="product.info.main" after="page.main.title" />
```

so it shows price after title within "product.info.main"

if Title is on proper place then no need to use "move" tag.. Because by default it's the first one to display on product page. everything should be after title.

Thanks. Hope this helps you